# Accessing deeply nested values inside a complex Object of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an Object that contains nested Objects and Arrays structured like the sample below:

```
{
  "5-1980": [
    {
      "memID": "180",
      "memType": "Movie",
      "date": {
        "month": 5,
        "year": 1980
      },
      "favourite": null,
      "public": null,
      "music": [],
      "movie": [
        {
          "poster": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original//7BuH8itoSrLExs2YZSsM01Qk2no.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "tvshow": [],
      "game": []
    },
    {
      "memID": "180",
      "memType": "Movie",
      "date": {
        "month": 5,
        "year": 1980
      },
      "favourite": null,
      "public": null,
      "music": [],
      "movie": [
        {
          "poster": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original//7BuH8itoSrLExs2YZSsM01Qk2no.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "tvshow": [],
      "game": []
    }
  ],
  "6-1980": [
    {
      "memID": "65",
      "memType": "Game",
      "date": {
        "month": 6,
        "year": 1980
      },
      "favourite": null,
      "public": null,
      "music": [],
      "movie": [],
      "tvshow": [],
      "game": [
        {
          "boxArt": "https://images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_1080p/co1hvj.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "7-1980": [
    {
      "memID": "178",
      "memType": "Movie",
      "date": {
        "month": 7,
        "year": 1980
      },
      "favourite": null,
      "public": null,
      "music": [],
      "movie": [
        {
          "poster": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original//5xcXvTErivIgRchsaw9qaT3NflE.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "tvshow": [],
      "game": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't work out how to access the values in the object, specifically the URLs, so that I can use them to render images. Using the data above as an example, I want to access the four URLs that are nested inside the Object, so that I can display the images grouped into an Array as per the below:

```
  [
    5-1980: [
      URL 1,
      URL 2
    ],
    6-1980: [
      URL 1
    ],  
    7-1980: [
     URL 1
    ]
  ]
```

Currently I'm able to render an element for each of the month-year groups by using `Object.keys(data).map((data, i) =>` but I then can't work out how to access each of the elements' associated image URLs.

As the URLs are nested in different Arrays depending on the `memType` I know that I will need to construct some `if` statements but I can't work out how to get to each of the objects in side the array associated with each month-year group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to iterate through and return and flatten intermediate result arrays of URLs. Of the values, specify the keys you want destructured and mapped from the nested properties.

```
Object.entries(data).flatMap(([key, value]) => [
  key,
  ...value.flatMap(({ game, movie }) => [
    ...movie.map(({ poster }) => `->${poster}`),
    ...game.map(({ boxArt }) => `->${boxArt}`),
    // spread in any other sub-category arrays with URLs
  ])
]);
```

```js
const data = {
  "5-1980": [
    {
      memID: "180",
      memType: "Movie",
      date: {
        month: 5,
        year: 1980
      },
      favourite: null,
      public: null,
      music: [],
      movie: [
        {
          poster:
            "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original//7BuH8itoSrLExs2YZSsM01Qk2no.jpg"
        }
      ],
      tvshow: [],
      game: []
    },
    {
      memID: "180",
      memType: "Movie",
      date: {
        month: 5,
        year: 1980
      },
      favourite: null,
      public: null,
      music: [],
      movie: [
        {
          poster:
            "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original//7BuH8itoSrLExs2YZSsM01Qk2no.jpg"
        }
      ],
      tvshow: [],
      game: []
    }
  ],
  "6-1980": [
    {
      memID: "65",
      memType: "Game",
      date: {
        month: 6,
        year: 1980
      },
      favourite: null,
      public: null,
      music: [],
      movie: [],
      tvshow: [],
      game: [
        {
          boxArt: "https://images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_1080p/co1hvj.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "7-1980": [
    {
      memID: "178",
      memType: "Movie",
      date: {
        month: 7,
        year: 1980
      },
      favourite: null,
      public: null,
      music: [],
      movie: [
        {
          poster:
            "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original//5xcXvTErivIgRchsaw9qaT3NflE.jpg"
        }
      ],
      tvshow: [],
      game: []
    }
  ]
};

const value = Object.entries(data).flatMap(([key, value]) => [
  key,
  ...value.flatMap(({ game, movie }) => [
    ...movie.map(({ poster }) => `-> ${poster}`),
    ...game.map(({ boxArt }) => `-> ${boxArt}`)
  ])
]);

console.log(value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this, it's a really good solution especially as it allows me to add other sub-categories. It doesn't quite get me where I want to be though - I've updated my question to be much clearer. I'd like to return a single array that contains an array for each month-year group that contains each url for that month-year. Thank you again for your help with this!

Comment: I've just been playing around with the code and can get what I need by changing `flatMap` to just `map` and then changing some of my other code. Thank you again for all your help! One other question - is it possible to add a static URL to one of the sub-categories using this solution i.e. `...event === 'SOME_URL'`?

Comment: @Sean If I understand what you're asking, to add a static URL to a sub-category, like movie, then I think something like this: `...[...movie.map(({ poster }) => \`->${poster}\`), 'SOME_URL'],` or `...movie.map(({ poster }) => \`->${poster}\`).concat(['SOME_URL])`.